# Use of comma after a conjunction

Tags: grammaticality, commas, oxford-comma

> Operationally, collective behavior was detected and quantified using correlations, or, more recently, by mutual information estimated either locally or globally.

Here should it be "or more recently" in place of "or, more recently"?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You've used the tag [serial-comma]: should one of your options be "...correlations or, more recently...", omitting the comma **before** *or*?

Comment: It is correct as it stands. the phrase "more recently" is parenthetic. That means that it could be left out of the sentence completely without destroying its meaning.The commas surrounding 'more recently' are a pair and work like brackets (in fact they could be replaced by brackets). Without the parenthesis the sentence would be "...correlations, or by mutual information...". As @AndrewLeach says the comma before the 'or' can be omitted. To make ,it clearer brackets could replace the parenthetic commas giving "...correlations or (more recently) by mutual information..."

Comment: @BoldBen it's certainly *correct* as it stands, but the comma before "or" adds clutter without adding clarity, I think.

Comment: @verbose I think so too. I think the questioner is analysing the sentence item by item rather than looking at it as a whole. This has led him to question the positioning of the comma after the conjunction rather than seeing it as one of a pair of commas surrounding a parenthetical phrase. As you say the  comma _before_ the conjunction is extraneous. I would also question the need for the one after "Operationally".

Comment: “Operationally collective behavior” could be interpreted entirely differently from “Operationally, collective behavior”: behavior that is operationally collective as opposed to behavior being detected and quantified operationally by the specified means.

Comment: Thank you @verbose for your help.

Comment: Thank you @BoldBen for your help.